# Geoserver heatmap in meters rather than pixels

Tags: geoserver, wms, leaflet, sld, heat-map

Is it possible to get the radius' density kernel of the heatmap in meters rather than in pixels?
http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/cartography/rt/heatmap.html

If not, is there other alternatives to draw heatmaps efficiently from my postgresql db and send it to leaflet? (I tried heatmap.js but it is quite slow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using a raster tool, the radius of your filter has to be expressed in pixels. If you need a more precise solution, you must use a smaller pixel size. This is a constraint from the method and not from the software.

If you need to start with an input value in meters, you can convert your "meters" in "number of pixels" in a previous step. This is quite straightforward if you are using a projected coordinate system (round(radius_in_meter/pixel_size)). If you are in lat/long, it is not recommended to use this kind of conversion.

Comment: Is it possible to use map units instead? I have created a grid of 50000 x 50000 cells in EPSG 3857 and would like to use something of this order as a radius (my wms layer will always be served in that projection). It is possible in QGIS for instance.